# How to force/trigger xamarin mono to GC from ADB shell?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono, adb

Trying this command **adb shell debug.mono.profile** for getting heap shot.

So what is the command to trigger GC from using adb shell?

Answer (score 3):

Add `BroadcastReceiver` to your app that calls `GC.Collect` in the `OnReceive` override.

Here is one that I use:

```
#if DEBUG
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = ReceiverName, Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { IntentFilterName })]
public class MonoGCBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string ReceiverName = "com.sushihangover.someapp.garbagecollect";
    const string IntentFilterName = "perform.mono.gc";
    readonly string TAG = Application.Context.PackageName;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == IntentFilterName)
        {
            var generation = intent.GetIntExtra("generation", 9999);
            if (!Enum.TryParse(intent.GetStringExtra("mode"), true, out GCCollectionMode mode))
            {
                mode = GCCollectionMode.Forced;
            }
            var force = intent.GetBooleanExtra("forced", true);
            var compacting = intent.GetBooleanExtra("compacting", true);
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"GC: G:{generation} : M:{mode} : F:{force} C:{compacting}");
            GC.Collect(generation, mode, force, compacting);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Now, you can use `adb` to call that receiver and pass the optional parameters for the garbage collector.

Example:

```
export packageName="com.sushihangover.someapp"

adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile log:heapshot

# Start you app

adb shell am broadcast \
  -n $packageName/.garbagecollect \
  -a perform.mono.gc \
  --es mode "force" \
  --ei generation 1 \
  --ez forced true

// Clear debug.mono.profile when all done collecting your mlpd
adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile '""'
```

Comment: @SushilHangover without change in code and only through adb shell can we trigger? is it possible?

Comment: @RahulBaradia No, I have not seen anything exposed in the Mono runtime that will receive a broadcast (or anything else via `adb`). If the app is in debug mode with the Mono Soft Debugger attached, you might be able to do it via a command over the debug wire protocol (but I do not think a VM command to do that is currently exposed..?).

Comment: @ShusilHangover Thank you :)